# How to create recurring event with every 2 days/weeks/months/years in Google Calendar API PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I want to create a google calendar event like this through Google Calendar API V3 in PHP,

**Repeat every 3 days/weeks/months/years with 5 cycles.**

I've checked, 
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

But how to add the event like that? Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to create is a [recurring event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents). Creating recurring events is similar to [creating](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) a regular (single) [`event`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) with the event resource's [recurrence](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#recurrence) field set. To learn more about recurrence rule, you can visit this [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurrence_rule).

An example of a recurring event is:

```
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$event->setSummary('Appointment');
$event->setLocation('Somewhere');
$start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00');
$start->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00');
$end->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$event->setEnd($end);
$event->setRecurrence(array('RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T170000Z'));
$attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
$attendee1->setEmail('attendeeEmail');
```

What makes this different from a single event is the following line:

```
$event->setRecurrence(array('RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T170000Z'));
```

This line makes the single event occur again every week until July 1.

Another example: An all-day event starting on June 1st, 2015 and repeating every 3 days throughout the month, excluding June 10th but including June 9th and 11th

```
...
"start": {
 "date": "2015-06-01"
},
"end": {
 "date": "2015-06-02"
},
"recurrence": [
 "EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20150610",
 "RDATE;VALUE=DATE:20150609,20150611",
 "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20150628;INTERVAL=3"
],
…
```

For your case, you may create a recurring event that has an `RRULE` of `FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20190229;INTERVAL=3` for every 3 days. Change `FREQ` to `WEEKLY` for every 3 weeks and `UNTIL` to adjust how many cycles.